# Tricky URL rewrite with custom values in url

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

We have custom post type as `user_images` and each of these post has a image attached with image name is 3 digit number followed by extension.

When the url

```
http://mysite.com/wp_username/3digitnumber
```

is accessed, we want to use a custom template inside theme to show the image

Tricky part is the url should remain same for visitor but internally should call the custom template with the `wp_username` and `3digitnumber` as query variable.
`wp_username` is valid WordPress user nicename.

Couldn't get a clue so made a minor compromise to url format

```
http://mysite.com/image/wp_username/3digitnumber
```

Tried creating a page using the custom template and used the following htaccess rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^iuser=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?post_type=page&p=564&iuser=$1&iname=$2 [L]
```

where 564 is the page id with custom template.

However the url changes to

```
http://mysite.com/custompage/?iuser=myuser&iname=001
```

Also tried

```
function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newrules['image/([^/]+)/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=page&p=564&iuser=$matches[1]&iname=$matches[2]';

    $rules = $newrules + $rules;
    return $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

(called `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` once after adding this.)

But again the url changes to

```
http://mysite.com/custompage/?iuser=myuser&iname=001
```

**Answer:**
Solution provided by @Milo works perfectly.
The url changed to one with query string because of Browser Cache

Comment: Consider using the Rewrite API instead - http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API and a very handy plugin that defines rewrites and helps utilizing them - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/

Comment: I tried adding `$newrules['image/([^/]+)/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=page&p=564&iuser=$matches[1]&iname=$matches[2]';` to `rewrite_rules_array` using filter. But ends up getting Memory allocation error.

Comment: @MarioPeshev tried Rewrite API but i guess i'm missing something.

Comment: as a side solution, you could use the template_include hook to apply a template dynamically, you have access to the $post global variable, including it's properties. I'm using that approach in a plugin of mine, the apply_remote_template function here - http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/dx-template-manager/trunk/dx-template-manager.php - though it's far safer to include a file instead as you would do.

Comment: @MarioPeshev thanks for comment. Looks like even if I use the template_include hook the url may not remain same. The Rewrite API is working but the url changes to `http://mysite.com/custompage/?iuser=myuser&iname=001` instead i want it to remain `http://mysite.com/custompage/myuser/001`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in your *other* question, you don't want to be touching the .htaccess file, you need an *internal* rewrite.

So, given the URL:

```
http://mysite.com/image/wp_username/3digitnumber
```

we need to add the following rule to handle it:

```
// set up the rewrite rule
function wpa73374_setup_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'image/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=custompage&iuser=$matches[1]&iname=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa73374_setup_rewrites' );
```

Note above, we point to a page with slug `custompage`. You can change that to whatever page slug you are using to handle these custom URLs. If the page is a child page of another, you must add `pagename=parentpage/childpage`. After adding rewrite rules, be sure to visit the permalinks settings page to flush rewrites so your new rules will begin working.

Now the above alone won't work though, because WordPress doesn't know what `iuser` and `iname` are, so we need to add those to recognized query vars:

```
// add your custom query vars
function wpa73374_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'iuser';
    $query_vars[] = 'iname';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa73374_query_vars' );
```

Then finally within the template, use `get_query_var( 'iuser' )` and `get_query_var( 'iname' )` to get your custom query var values.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. Your code works but the only issue is when I go to the url `http://mysite.com/image/wpusername/001` it redirects to `http://mysite.com/image?iuser=wpusername&iname=001`. Instead I want the url SEO friendly and unchanged. (Note I changed pagename to image itself instead of custompage)

Comment: did you remove the rules you added to .htaccess?

Comment: yes I did removed the rules from .htaccess, only default WordPress rules are there. Also flushed rewrites again.

Comment: There is similar question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25241/url-rewrite-page-custom-post-type-unusual-redirect?rq=1 but couldn't see working answer in that as well.

Comment: is `image` an existing page? I've tested in twentyeleven and it's working as expected. it seems like you have some conflict with htaccess or additional rules you've added elsewhere.

Comment: yes `image` is the page with custom template set.

Comment: When you check does the url remains same ??

Comment: yes, if you are using pretty permalinks, that's how WordPress internal rewrites work

Comment: Quite strange, I changed theme to TwentyEleven and tried still the url changes from `http://mysite.com/image/wpusername/001` to `http://mysite.com/image/?iuser=wpusername&iname=001` (I did copied the custom template to TwentyEleven directory)

Comment: Finally found the issue, it was the browser cache that kept redirecting to the url with query string.